# Access label, title in pgpfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to know if is possible to access the standard `nodes` in `pgfplots` such as `ylabel, xlabel, title`. I am pretty sure this is quite easy, since each `node` should have a name by which it can be called, but I don't know how to figure this name out and the name, I would expect them to have, does not exist.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title={Some title}, ylabel={ylabel}, xlabel={xlabel}]
            \addplot+[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (2,3)};
            % Does not work
            \draw (ylabel.center) -> (title.center);
            \draw (ylabel.center) -> (xlabel.west);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes aren't named by default, but you can assign names yourself using `title style={name=title}`, for instance. The title and labels are generated at the very end of the `axis` environment, so if you want to refer to these nodes, you'll have to mode your TikZ commands outside the `axis` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          title={Some title}, title style={name=title},
          ylabel={ylabel}, ylabel style={name=ylabel},
          xlabel={xlabel}, xlabel style={name=xlabel}
        ]
        \addplot+[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (2,3)};
        \end{axis}

        \draw (ylabel.center) -> (title.center);
        \draw (ylabel.center) -> (xlabel.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, too bad that the nodes cannot be accessed inside the axis-environment, not even with `after end axis/.code`. I would have expected them to be defined earlier.

Comment: @maetra: Yeah, I was a bit surprised by that as well. What are you trying to do? Maybe there's a different approach?

Comment: I am trying to draw a line from the left to the right of the whole graph, which I use for a custom legend. The point most far to the left, is determined by the ylabel and for the right side I use `(rel axis cs:1,0)`. Apart from the axis environment `(rel axis cs:1,0)` is not correct anymore, but shifted to the left. This not a big problem, since I split the drawing in two parts, but for the legend text this is a pain.

Comment: @maetra: In that case, a better approach would be to use `\draw (current axis.outer west) -- (current axis.outer east);` outside the `axis` environment. That approach is more robust, since it will also work in cases where you don't have a `ylabel`, for example.

Comment: that is good hint, I'll try that approach